# Is it possible to apply my own decorators to builtin methods in Python?

Tags: python, decorator

I've just come across Python decorators. Just out of interest, can you apply your own decorator to a built-in object method somehow? Say I wanted to apply this:

```
def remove_empty(fn):
    def filtered():
        return filter(lambda x: x != '', fn())
    return filtered
```

To this:

```
some_string.split('\n')
```

in order to remove empty strings. Is it possible? Or even a good idea?

Comment: You want the split() method to always remove empty strings on every call in your application?

Comment: Good point. It might be a bad example, but I'd still like to know if it's possible...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible in a sense; it depends on what exactly you mean. Decorator syntax like this...

```
@dec
def foo():
    pass
```

is really just sugar for this:

```
def foo():
    pass
foo = dec(foo)
```

So there's nothing to stop you from using a decorator on a predefined function in the global namespace.

```
func = dec(func)
```

But the methods of built-in classes live in the namespace of that class, and that namespace can't be modified directly, as [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476484/577088) has already pointed out. That's a good thing, because it ensures that objects of type `str` will behave as expected! However, you could *subclass* str and decorate the method that way. (The below works in Python 2; in Python 3, pass the output of `filter` to a list. `super` also may work a little differently; I'll post a Python 3 update in the future.)

```
>>> def remove_empty(fn):
...     def filtered(*args, **kwargs):
...         return filter(lambda x: x != '', fn(*args, **kwargs))
...     return filtered
... 
>>> class WeirdString(str):
...     @remove_empty
...     def split(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         return super(WeirdString, self).split(*args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> 'This decorator is unnecessary\n\n\n'.split('\n')
['This decorator is unnecessary', '', '', '']
>>> WeirdString('This decorator is unnecessary\n\n\n').split('\n')
['This decorator is unnecessary']
```

Or more directly (and so more in the spirit of decorator use):

```
>>> class WeirdString2(str):
...     split = remove_empty(str.split)
... 
>>> WeirdString2('This decorator is unnecessary\n\n\n').split('\n')
['This decorator is unnecessary']
```

In the case of this *particular* example, I'd prefer an explicit filter. But I can imagine, for example, a subclass of a built-in class that does some [memoization](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) or something like that.

Comment: It's also possible to make your subclass replace the existing `str` by replacing the built-in: `__builtins__.str = WeirdString`. This doesn't affect the `''` or `""` constructors, though, and should only be done if you really understand what you're doing.

Comment: Does this work in Python 3? Instead of `['This decorator is unnecessary']`, I get `<filter at 0x4d3b9b0>`.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, not quite, because in Python 3 the value returned by `filter` is an iterator instead of a list. So the call to `filter` would need to be wrapped in a call to `list`. I'll add a note -- thanks for the comment!

Comment: I see. Well, if I try `list[filter(...` I get TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: It would be `list(filter(...`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid the answer is no. Decorators are applied when the function is defined, and `str.split` is pre-defined. You might think you could do something explicit like

```
str.split = remove_empty(str.split)
```

but that is not permitted:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 8, in <module>
    str.split = remove_empty(str.split)
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'str'
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is.  Just write

```
remove_empty(lambda: some_string.split('\n'))()
```

Comment: This just returns a new function that you would need to call again to filter `some_string`. It does not apply a decorator to `str.split`.

Comment: @chepner it applies a decorator to a function, and calls the result.

Comment: Sorry, parenthesis blindness. I didn't see the extra pair at the end to call the function.