# Decorating Python's builtin print() function

Tags: python, python-decorators

As we know in Python 3 `print()` is a function, is it possible to create a decorated version of it wrapped under `json.dumps(indent=4)`

for ex.

Calling `print(mydict)` should produce the same result as `print(json.dumps(mydict, indent=4))`

Comment: Why does this have to be a decorator?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need a decorator per se to do that.  Just define a new function and call it `print`:

```
import builtins

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    builtins.print(json.dumps(*args, **kwargs, indent=4))
```

You can use the `builtins` module as shown to access the original print function.

The thing is that doing this doesn't really gain anything over calling your new function something besides `print`, except it will confuse people.

If you want to *really* confuse people you could store `old_print = builtins.print`, define your new function as `my_print` (accessing the original as `old_print`) and then do `builtins.print = my_print`.  Then your modified `print` will actually replace the regular `print`, even in other modules that know nothing about your shenanigans.  But that is an even worse idea.

Comment: Thanks for the elegant use of `builtins` module, It's very handy and clever solution indeed.

Comment: would recommend calling it e.g. iprint though, for indent.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from BrenBarn's answer(accepted), posting another [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c6ee1be4befc1c38d34cd02553b31945) here by @Adam Smith

```
import builtins
import functools
import json

orig_print = builtins.print

def indent4(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(json.dumps(*args, **kwargs, indent=4))
    return wrapped

@indent4
def print(*args, **kwargs):
    return orig_print(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, take a look at pprint.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html

Answer (score -3):

No, it's not possible since `print` is a builtin function and it's not even a builtin C-level class. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476402/is-it-possible-to-apply-my-own-decorators-to-builtin-methods-in-python) provides a way to subclass a builtin object like a `str` and apply a decorator to one of it's methods.

Comment: @AdamSmith Barn's answer isn't using a decorator. That's what the question originally asked.

Comment: Done with a decorator here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c6ee1be4befc1c38d34cd02553b31945