# print a double backslash in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

As I was carefully checking a parser script I wrote, I realised that it has done something to the values in some key-value pairs containing double backslash. After a while, realised it was the natural behaviour of `print` I was seeing, eg:

```
>>> print("some\\thin")
some\thin
```

It loses a backslash. When I first wrote the parser, used print so I could see the output and iterate. When it was ready to go, I opened a file at the start of the program, closed it at the end and put a `, file=f` into every print statement.

Does anyone know how to lightly modify the `print` command so that it will print both backslashes?

That may be a bit inelegant or dangerous, so I'd be happy to just add something into the for loop otherwise:

```
strings_list = ["something_normal", "someth\\ing_unusual"]

for string in strings_list:
    if "\\" in string:
        # something needs to go here which prints 
        # a string containing a backslash to the file f
        pass
    else:
        print(string)
```

Comment: `print(r'some\\thin')`.  If you want to use a loop see my duplicate below on how to to turn a `str` into a raw string. (i.e.  `print(%r" % string)`

Comment: Thanks, playing around with the raw string, I could come up with a line to go after that `if` statement which makes it work: `print(string.replace("\\", "\\\\"))`

Comment: Furthermore, was able to modify the behaviour of `print` inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46658735/4288043) solution. `if "\\" in args[0]:` ,  `builtins.print(args[0].replace("\\", "\\\\"), **kwargs)`