# How to write to something that can be returned from a function

Tags: python, file, printing

I have a function that does a lot of prints. I want these to go to stdout as well as to a file, so I currently have to duplicate every print: once for stdout and once for the file.

Is there a way I can print to something (not sure what!) that I can return from the function and simply print with two print statements in my calling script?

So instead of:

```
def func():
   print("1")
   print("1",file=out.txt)
   print("2")
   print("2",file=out.txt)
   print("3")
   print("3",file=out.txt)
   return()
```

I want something like:

```
def func2():
   print("1",  ???) ->string.out
   print("2",  ???) ->string.out
   print("3",  ???) ->string.out
   (or some such?)
   return(string.out)

func2()
print(string.out)
print(string.out,file=out.txt)
```

I know I can do it in a crude fashion by appending all my output to a string but this would involve lots of formatting that "print" takes care of (eg. with template).

Or maybe that's the answer - I just can't see how to do it in a neat pythonic fashion.

Comment: Why don't you just use `tee` command ?

Comment: I don't think I understood the problem. Why can't you define your own `my_print` function that prints the same thing to both stdout and the file?

Comment: So basically what you want is the output to be in console and the file at the same time ?

Comment: You can "overload" builtins.print. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658639/decorating-pythons-builtin-print-function

Comment: The `multiprint` function would work but I was looking for something that did the printing in the main routine (for various reasons).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to define your own print function and call it instead of calling `print`.

```
def multiprint(data, *files):
    print(data)  # prints out to stdout
    for file in files:
        print(data, stdout=file)
```

And you can call this function as:

```
multiprint("print this", file1, file1, file3)
```

All you have to do is, replace all `print` function calls with `multiprint` calls.

---

Or, you can write a decorator, but it would be a horrible approach.

```
from functools import wraps
import sys

def multiprint(*files):
    def printnew(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner():
            func()
            _stdout = sys.stdout
            for file in files:
                sys.stdout = file  # a bit of dirty monkey patching
                func()
            sys.stdout = _stdout
        return inner
    return printnew


@multiprint(file1, file2)
def f():
    print('first')
    print('second')

f()  # first and second will be printed to stdout and into both file1 and file2
```